# how to display result returned from google places api text search in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to use Google places api text search in my android application,for finding location on map.So I looked for it and got this query:

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?location=-41.319282,174.818717&radius=1000&sensor=true&query=cafe&key=My Browser Key"
```

But I don't Know,how to display the results on map.Can I have any example for getting result and displaying it on map using Google map places api text search feature?

Comment: Parse the response and show places using marker

Comment: try this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/